# created a table in Snowflake but the table did not return the expected number of rows

Tags: sql

first time poster here. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I wrote a query in Snowflake that I wanted to store it as a table instead of running the query every single time. The query had **385,399** number of rows.

But when I created a table in using the same query and upon doing a simple validation check, the table returned **385,286** rows.

Sample query as I am using company data

Query that I wanted to store in a table

```
with abc as (
    ... 

, final as (
    ....
)

select * from final;
```

Query used to create table

```
create table temp_table as 
{insert query from above}
;
```